# What should be the format of input to MultilayerPerceptronClassifier function in MLlib Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, neural-network, word2vec

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassifier
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

// Load training data
val data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc,"data/mllib/sample_multiclass_classification_data.txt").toDF()
// Split the data into train and test
val splits = data.randomSplit(Array(0.6, 0.4), seed = 1234L)
val train = splits(0)
val test = splits(1)
// specify layers for the neural network: 
// input layer of size 4 (features), two intermediate of size 5 and 4 and output of size 3 (classes)
val layers = Array[Int](4, 5, 4, 3)
// create the trainer and set its parameters
val trainer = new MultilayerPerceptronClassifier()
  .setLayers(layers)
  .setBlockSize(128)
  .setSeed(1234L)
  .setMaxIter(100)
// train the model
val model = trainer.fit(train)
// compute precision on the test set
val result = model.transform(test)
val predictionAndLabels = result.select("prediction", "label")
val evaluator = new MulticlassClassificationEvaluator().setMetricName("precision")
println("Precision:" + evaluator.evaluate(predictionAndLabels))
```

I have this sample code. The input file "data/mllib/sample_multiclass_classification_data.txt" is in following format:

```
1 1:-0.222222 2:0.5 3:-0.762712 4:-0.833333 
1 1:-0.555556 2:0.25 3:-0.864407 4:-0.916667 
1 1:-0.722222 2:-0.166667 3:-0.864407 4:-0.833333 
1 1:-0.722222 2:0.166667 3:-0.694915 4:-0.916667
```

My input file (CSV):

```
Help me with my Account Balance, Balance
Want to know my Balance, Balance
What is the available Balance in my Account, Balance
Balance in Account, Balance
Available bank Balance, Balance
Help me with my Account Balance, Balance
Want to know my Balance, Balance
What is the available Balance in my Account, Balance
Balance in Account, Balance
```

My output looks like:

`key Balance - 0.0036513722,7.4863195E-4,0.0026168288,0.0018019283,3.6993028E-5,0.0015877665,-0.0023806596,-0.0044850614,0.0030128842,-0.0027919186,0.0029404194,0.001331976,-0.00244722,-0.0022837287,0.0033935083,-1.0614514E-4,0.004019062,0.0018543076,6.72285E-4,0.0019381851,0.0018775725,-0.0029566616,0.0039101024,0.0016479599,0.0023191334,0.0032120477,5.984378E-4,-4.9780607E-5,-4.5533956E-4,0.0019212944,-0.0014106851,0.0037013923,0.0043562353,8.073688E-4,0.004751688,0.0021792704,-5.208015E-4,-0.0033827745,-5.3768157E-4,0.0044863885,-0.0031513213,0.0023239064,0.0035973901,-0.0047605466,-0.0040854285,-0.0045714066,-0.001879341,0.0042538918,-0.004887264,0.0026716448,0.004494503,-3.7978767E-4,-0.0023598725,0.0047358125,-7.927376E-4,-0.0028520639,0.0019070529,1.3333082E-4,0.0016852015,0.0028981792,0.0042936187,-0.0010523892,0.0043657385,0.0028728675,0.0024622548,-0.0021084119,0.0022188448,-7.240367E-4,-0.004585674,-0.0032908982,-0.002840305,0.0017878491,0.0047972207,0.0012684285,-4.1861474E-4,0.0021237314,-0.0030996585,3.7243307E-4,0.004151346,0.0025370778,-0.0022359376,1.0996461E-5,0.0026262754,5.540156E-4,-0.0041488777,-0.0024115837,0.0017715782,-0.0032798958,4.7829092E-4,6.21534E-4,0.003895337,0.004436586,0.0029779458,-0.0015637607,6.298947E-4,0.0029944445,-2.794385E-4,-0.004432401,0.0034545213,0.002706862`

I want to perform following operation: Input -> word2vec -> output -> neural network,
But the output format of sample code doesn't match with my output. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Could you show the output of the sample code ?

Comment: Issue resolved. Thank you

Comment: You should post the answer to help anyone in the same as you in the future.

Comment: The output of word2vector looks like this:
[-0.06920687747853142,0.04828440344759396,0.040697344185900874,-0.017867059313825196]
and input for MultilayerPerceptronClassifier should be in following format:
3 1:-0.040327 2:0.054813 3:0.034227 4:-0.033958
where 3 denotes the label or class and 1,2,3,4 denotes number of features